# Upload my own videos to Google Play?

Tags: google-play-store, sync, video

Is it possible to sync my own video with Google Play Video (like in Google Play Music)?

I know that it's not possible on Google Books, I am wondering how about videos.

What will be a good alternative for syncing videos?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now it is not possible to sync through Play Video, however, you may [soon be able to purchase movies from the market and have them stay in the cloud until needed.](http://news.cnet.com/8301-31001_3-57402846-261/google-play-mulls-movie-sales/)

You could try alternatives such as [Box](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.box.android&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5ib3guYW5kcm9pZCJd), or Dropbox, (there are many competitors in this file-locker space), they allows you to sync nearly anything across devices.

Google Video, at least on my Xoom, will pick up movies out of any folder without the .nomedia file in it.

(edited to remove falsehood of no Google Services allowing syncing :) )

Comment: And what if I have a video of my wedding and wanna upload? I guess I'm looking for an alternative, which is?

Comment: It is very possible to sync videos via Google's services.  Take a look at Google+ and Picasa.  I have all my personal videos (and photos) uploaded to Picasa Web Albums, and can access them via the Gallery app on my phone.  Google+ app allows me to auto-upload videos taken on the phone to my G+ account, which is the same place as the Picasa Albums.

Comment: IMHO they should have make it a unified service Music, Videos, Books, Podcasts (listen), all should be accessed and managed from one place. Whatcha think?

Comment: There has been talk/rumors about a Google offered File Locker service in the works - [Google Drive](http://gizmodo.com/5888092/rumor-google-drive-will-play-nice-with-third+party-apps)

Answer (score 3):

If you use Google+, you could install the [Google+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.plus) app which can auto-upload videos and photos from your phone to your G+ account.

These photos and videos can also be accessed online via [Picasa Web Albums](https://picasaweb.google.com) which point to the same place as your Google+ photo albums.  On the phone these become visible in the built-in Gallery app, if you enable the `Sync Google Photos` and `Sync Google+` options on your account via `Settings -> Accounts & sync -> <your Google account>`.  On the desktop you can use Google's own [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com/) application to organize and sync your photos/videos between your PC and your Google account.

Comment: Can it also sync my DVDs from my computer to my device?

Comment: Copyright debate aside, it should be possible if you rip the DVDs into supported video formats.  However, Google's "cloud" storage that's in use by Google+ and Picasa is only free for the first 1 GB (some files don't count toward this limit.)  After that limit is reached, you'll need to upgrade to paid storage.  See this article for details: http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=39567